# Fortran error: rank mismatch in spread()

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Here is a simple code that tests the `spread` intrinsic function:

```
program test_spread
   implicit none

   integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: a
   integer, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: b
   integer, allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: c
   integer, allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: d

   allocate(a(2), b(2,4), c(2,4,2), d(2,4,2))

   a(:) = [1, 2]
   print*, "a=", a

   b(:,:) = spread((a + 1)**2, 2, size(b,2))
   print*, "b=", b

   c(:,:,:) = spread(b, 3, size(c,3))
   print*, "c=", c

   d(:,:,:) = spread(spread((a + 1)**2, 2, size(d,2)), 3, size(d,3))
   print*, "d=", d
end program
```

It is compiled with gfortran 8.1.1:

```
gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall -Wtabs -fbacktrace -c test.f90
gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall -Wtabs -fbacktrace -o test_spread test.o
```

I get the following result:

```
 a=           1           2
 b=           4           9           4           9           4           9           4           9
 c=           4           9           4           9           4           9           4           9           4           9           4           9           4           9           4           9

Fortran runtime error: rank mismatch in spread()

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x55b46b14386e in test_spread
    at /*****/test_spread/test.f90:20
#1  0x55b46b143966 in main
    at /*****/test_spread/test.f90:22
```

If I remove the `allocatable` attribute, the code compiles and gives the correct result. Am I doing anything wrong or is it a compiler error?

The code compiles and gives the correct result with Intel Fortran 18.

PS: I am using GCC on Arch Linux on a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4114 CPU.

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.1.1 20180531
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: FWIW the code compiles and runs without complaint on my installation using GFortran 8.0.0.  And I can't see anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 3):

2018-06-01  Steven G. Kargl

```
    PR fortran/85816
    PR fortran/85975
    * libgfortran.h: Remove the GFC_DTYPE_COPY_SETRANK macro.
    * intrinsics/reshape_generic.c: Directly assign rank.
    * intrinsics/spread_generic.c: Ditto.
    ...
    * m4/spread.m4: Ditto.
```

Comment: Are you indicating here that it is a compiler bug in gfortran 8.1.1 and that this has been fixed or will be fixed? Please elaborate a little bit at the moment it is a bit cryptic.

Comment: Chaining 3 questions into a single sentence makes it difficult to answer.  Anyway, yes and yes.

Comment: Only 2 answers to 3 questions !

Comment: The 3rd question is moot given the answers to the other two.